# What does "a working majority of just 16" imply?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Of course, Britain is now in unknown, volatile territory. Brexit strains, combined with **a working majority of just 16**, could force her to seek a personal mandate from voters at an early election, or even bring down her premiership. At times the year will feel like a long series of arm-wrestles between the legislature and the executive. But Mrs May is cautious and, with neither Labour nor the UK Independence Party in a good state, will probably resist the temptation to cash in on her soaring poll leads. Indeed, these should help her keep a lid on impatience and dissent in her party.

What does the number **16** imply? Does that mean the party has half of the seats and **16** more?

Answer (score 1):

The House of Commons is made up of 650 MPs each one elected to represent one of the 650 Parlimentary Constituencies in the UK.

A 16 seat working majority means that the party Prime Minister May lead, the Conservatves had 16 MPs sitting in the house more than all the other parties in the House of Commons combined.

Because of certain issues such as the Irish Republican parties not taking up their places in the House if elected as inorder to do so they would be required to swear an oath of loyalty to the Queen it's not quite the same as half the seats plus 16. In the last Parliment they had 330 seats only 5 seats above 325 but 16 more than the total number of MPs from other parties actually taking ther places in the House.